# unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515. Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: ruby, linux, google-chrome, selenium, amazon-ec2

I am setting up my `selenium-webdriver` tests with Linux and working on automating my tests with Cron Jobs. When running my script I am receiving this error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
   unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
```

`which chromedriver` returns:

`/usr/bin/chromedriver`

and `which google-chrome-stable` returns:

`/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

I thought that the error was related to not having Chrome installed yet, so I did that, but has not seemed to fix my issue.

How can I work through this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code trials please?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, locate your chromedriver (possibly /usr/bin) and check your dependencies:

```
ldd /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

It is likely you'll be missing at least libgconf-2

If this is the case, try this to resolve: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229187